# JQuery prepend takes a second to enter div on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a list navigation of which i want it to be inside another div on my web page (in particular inside a column) which i have achieved. The problem is upon page load (for a split second) momentarily it appears on the actual position before execution of the JQuery script to the desired position. How do i stop the split second jump on page load?

```
<div id="target">
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
$('#destination').prepend( $('#target') );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your element hidden, and only show it when moving it to the new destination, it will avoid some of the flicker you're seeing

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#destination').prepend( $('#target').show() );
});
```

```css
#destination {
  background-color:blue
}
#target {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="destination"></div>
```

Comment: Wondered if the JQuery root is any stable than a Java Script version. Thanks for looking through this Jamiec, it works great!

Comment: or just add `#destination #target { display: block; }` in CSS to prevent inline-styles using `.show()`

Comment: Thanks again Jamiec. Wondered if anyone knows a vanilla js version to the JQuery prepend?

Comment: @Lan.m [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) perhaps.